# Login task using servlet for website

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

How to prevent user from 2nd login in a day only one time login in  day,using servlet session management or jsp i need help for this could you explain give hint for this problem.

Comment: Save the login date. Compare this date with date at login time

Comment: thanks ..but could you give some additional hint.

Comment: Where are you stuck. I mean what is the issue which you are facing ?

Comment: could you give some coding ex for i didn't know how to perform.i'm new bee in servlet.

Comment: There's not enough detail here to answer any question.  Perhaps you're interested in extending the session timeout (not recommended due to security)?  Maybe you want to lock a user out of a website once they've logged in (why would you want to do that)?

Comment: i already store login date when user login but i don't know to how to prevent.i have one login dao class in that we fetch user from db and date also.\

Comment: Please go through this link. This will help you in completing your assignment

Comment: i think it can be also possible by using session or not.

Comment: Hi jabir u dn't send me link

Answer (score 1):

Save latest login time in database and compare it with current date on login.